Not reaching optimal parameter values for my neural network
I am trying to create a classification neural network using only the NumPY library for it. I have completely made the network and worked through the logic of it, and it seems perfectly fine to me. I don't know what is causing it to not reach the optimal parameters value. One of the important things that I have noticed is that the weights in the first layer do not change whatsoever.
What could be causing the code to not work as it is supposed to?
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], -1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], -1)
x_train, x_test = x_train/255, x_test/255
print(x_train.shape)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)
ohe.fit(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
y_train = ohe.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
y_test = ohe.transform(y_test.reshape(-1,1))
print(y_train.shape)

def linear(x,deriv=False):
    return x

def relu(x,deriv=False):
    if deriv:
        return (x > 0).astype(float)
    return np.maximum(0,x)

def softmax(x,deriv=False):
    xre = x - x.max(axis=0,keepdims=True)
    xexp = np.exp(xre)
    a = xexp.sum(axis=0,keepdims=True)
    prob = xexp/a
    return prob

def sigmoid(x,deriv=False):
    a = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    if deriv:
        return a * (1 - a)
    return a

activations = {'linear':linear,'relu':relu,'sigmoid':sigmoid,'softmax':softmax}

def initialvals(cols=784):
    shape = [cols,10,10]
    w = dict()
    b = dict()
    for i in range(len(shape)-1):
        w[i+1] = np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,(shape[i+1],shape[i]))

    for i in range(len(shape)-1):
        b[i+1] = np.zeros((shape[i+1],1))
    return w,b

def allprints(ww,bb):
    print('Weights')
    for i in ww:
        print(ww[i].shape)
    print('Biases')
    for i in bb:
        print(bb[i].shape)

    print('Weights')
    for i in ww:
        print(i)
        print(ww[i])
        print()
    print('Biases')
    for i in bb:
        print(i)
        print(bb[i])
        print()

def forprop(inputs,weight,bias,acts,av):
    z = dict()
    a = dict()
    
    z[0] = inputs.T
    a[0] = acts[av[0]](z[0])
    
    for i in range(1,len(weight)+1):
        z[i] = np.dot(weight[i],a[i-1]) + bias[i]
        a[i] = acts[av[i]](z[i])
    return z,a

def backprop(inputs, output, weight, bias, acts, av, size=50, iters=20, lr=0.01):
    n_samples = inputs.shape[0]
    global z_in
    for k in range(iters):
        shuff = np.random.permutation(n_samples)
        inputs = inputs[shuff]
        output = output[shuff]
        
        for i in range(0, n_samples, size): 
            batch_inputs = inputs[i:i + size]
            batch_output = output[i:i + size]
            z, a = forprop(batch_inputs, weight, bias, acts, av)
            z_in = z
            er = dict()
            er[len(bias)] = a[len(bias)] - batch_output.T 
            for j in range(len(bias)-1, 0, -1):
                er[j] = np.dot(weight[j + 1].T, er[j + 1]) * acts[av[j]](z[j], deriv=True)
                # delta_h = np.transpose(w_h_o) @ delta_o * (h * (1 - h))

            for j in range(1, len(bias) + 1):
                bias[j] -= lr * er[j].mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
                weight[j] -= lr * (np.dot(er[j], a[j - 1].T) / batch_inputs.shape[0])
    return weight, bias, er ,z_in

we,be = initialvals()
allprints(we,be)
w_calc, b_calc, er, z= backprop(x_train,y_train,we,be,activations,['linear','sigmoid','softmax'])
allprints(w_calc,b_calc)

I have checked the error values as well as the shapes for the operations that doesn't seem to be the problem.
I have tried different learning rates as well as taking different batch sizes and I even tried the same setup using the tensorflow library and it was giving good predictions so the model structure is not the issue.
I also have tried to initialize my parameters in different ways like random.randn, zeros, etc.

If the weights of the 1st layer don't change, I would imagine that it's because the backpropagation doesn't go untill the 1st layer. Have you checked your code with this in mind? e.g. as you know with for j in range(len(bias)-1, 0, -1), j will never see 0.

No dude, it does go into the j=1 iteration and i even get error values for that layer

your first layer has the index 1 and it is the one whose weight don't change?

Yeash precisely

In a single iteration the weights change slightly but in the next iteration the weights go back to the initial values

what is the cost function you use for the classification and its derivative?

Categorical cross entropy and it's derivative is what I don't remember. It's not needed here as when you use softmax along with this cost function the error of last layer becomes activation of last layer minus the y one hot encoded for that batch or observation
